# How to convert XML data into a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xml, nsmutablearray

I'm receiving data in XML from a server through a `NSData` object and I would like to convert this data to a `NSMutableArray` object.

How do I convert the data from the `NSData` object (knowing that there should be different objects transferred into the `NSMutableArray` - UIImages ,CLLocation2D objects, strings,...)

Comment: NSXML Parser..Do you know about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Give you a [URL](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=NSXMLParser&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CFoQFjACOAo&url=http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser&ei=ixgFUKLNKoSfiAf4w-HQCQ&usg=AFQjCNEJHUq_4l9YP3SJanINeKYVDT2HZg&cad=rjt), check it by yourself, it is easy to solve.